# Owl's job (meaning)

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

I found this expression "This is usually the owl's job". Is "the owl's job" an idiomatic expression? If it is, what does it mean?

I don't have much context information. This expression comes from an AFV episode and in the clip you see a dog licking a lollipop. The voiceover says: "This is usually the owl's job, but Riley is always ready to help out".

Comment: It's not an expression. It's just humorous.

Comment: I've seen this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583535/) on EL&U, it got closed for lack of detail. This is better but what is AFV??

Comment: AFV = America's Funniest Home Videos. It is a popular TV program about families and animals.

Comment: Where there any videos of owls before this was shown? What is the episode, is there a YouTube link?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, the videos are all stand alone send-ins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pop culture reference to the [Tootsie Pop commercial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NnuHGeCMd4E) that originally aired in the 70s. Tootsie Pops are lollipops that have a chocolate taffy in the center called a Tootsie Roll, which is also available as its own candy.  Even without re-watching the video, I can tell you the lines:

> **Boy**: Mr. Owl, how many licks does it take to get to the Tootsie Roll center of a Tootsie pop?
> **Owl**: Let's find out. [Licks lollipop] A-one, a-two-hoo, a-three! [Bites lollipop]

It's an iconic commercial that was definitely still airing (at least the owl part) when America's Funniest Videos (AFV) was.

---

Note: Do not allow your dogs to eat chocolate. It's [toxic](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/chocolate-poisoning-in-dogs).

Comment: If that's one of America's funniest videos, I'd hate to think what some of the duller ones are like.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The standard of craziness was very tame compared to YouTube, but in its time it was the primary source of random moments of cats failing to make ambitious jumps, dogs sliding across freshly waxed hardwood floors, children accidentally uttering blasphemies, teeter-totters where a heavy person at one end and a light one at the other can't figure out how to make it go back down, and so on. We used to enjoy it before being desensitized to all that by having it on demand in infinite quantities. Also, half the fun was how unbelievably obnoxious the narrator was.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - I promise you we still have these in the UK, with large brides falling on their backsides at weddings, roving news reporters saying the F-word when a bird shat on their head, yes, over-ambitious cats, dogs, and skateboarders, cursing parrots, newly built sheds collapsing, old people tumbling into paddling pools, bridesmaid making a speech next to a candle, not noticing her hair going on fire and being saved by the bride chucking wine on her head, farting babies. etc. The first host of the most famous series had a deformed hand, and he was obnoxious too.